# Could Superheavy land downrange and return if Starship were launched from Boca Chica?

Tags: spacex-starship, spacex-super-heavy

While answering a question about [Starship versus skyhooks](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/65264/could-starship-lift-mass-to-orbit-both-low-and-geo-stationary-cheaper-than-a-s/65273#65273), I discovered that there is a big difference in payload between a Falcon 9 launch where the booster lands downrange on a drone ship and one where it returns to the launch site.

[image: Performance Query]
[NASA Launch Services Program Launch Vehicle Performance Website](https://elvperf.ksc.nasa.gov/Pages/Results.aspx)

For the 400 km orbit (lowest the tool supports for Falcon 9) the payload supported drops by a factor of...

$$RTLS/ASDS = 11700/15500 ~= 0.75$$

This got me thinking, is it possible that Starship could increase its payload if Superheavy landed "downrange" on a (perhaps artificially constructed) island or platform in the gulf of Mexico somewhere, assuming that SpaceX built a Mechazilla tower on said island or platform?

[image]

Is there a site that is both in a suitable location and shallow enough to build an island or platform on? If so, would it even make sense to land there, refill the booster, and fly it back to Boca Chika?

Comment: Not directly relevant to your question, but launching from East from Vandenberg and recovering into a land site with return by land or reflight has been proposed at various times, mostly limited by liability concerns than technical ones. The fun proposal would be to have launch sites around the globe, and have the first stages recovered one hop East each launch.