# What is the TRL of a skyhook?

Tags: future-missions, development, skyhook, trl

A recent [answer](https://space.stackexchange.com/a/65291/44505) on [this question](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/65264/44505) mentioned that skyhooks have a low [TRL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Technology_readiness_level). This is probably due to many factors since they have not been built yet.

What is the current TRL/status of skyhooks and what is the next step needed to get them to a higher TRL?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There's a detailed breakdown of TRLs of various subsystems in [Boeing's 2001 HASTOL architecture report](https://www.niac.usra.edu/files/studies/final_report/391Grant.pdf). Bottom line is that the overall TRL is 2, though many of the subsystems have much higher TRLs.

The next step needed, a cynical person might suggest, is to secure several billion dollars in funding.